# Prove the expected value of a normal variable

Tags: expected-value

I would like to ask how would I prove that if $X$ is a normal variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $\mathbb{E}e^{u(X-\mu)} = e^{\frac{1}{2}u^2\sigma^2}$?

Comment: Since you have not shown any effort it is hard to guess what kind of proof will be accessible to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$ it is easy to prove that

$$Y=u(X-\mu)\sim N(0;\sigma^2 u^2)$$

Thus

$e^Y$ is [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distributed with mean $e^{\frac{\sigma^2 u^2}{2}}$